# Grunt Error Cannot find module 'win-spawn'

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, ionic-framework

I just installed Generator-ionic
in the folder where i genrated the app im trying to run grunt server
i get this error Error: Cannot find module 'win-spawn'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why the dependency is not being met, but it happened here too.

Solution:

`npm install win-spawn`

**Edit:**
Generator-ionic team is aware of the issue: https://github.com/diegonetto/generator-ionic/issues/162